# Update Table Entry with Algorithm

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm

I have table of entries with 5000 rows. now I would like to add two more column with the reference of first column. (i.e) First entry should be compared with all the entries and should not be compared with same value. (i.e) if the value "a" is take for comparison, then "a" should be compared with all the entries in same column but not same value. Consider the following example

This is the table which i have.

```
----------
entry1
----------
a
b
c
d
```

expected table output is

```
----------------------
 entry 2 | entry 3
----------------------
a   | b
a   | c
a   | d
b   | a
b   | c
b   | d
c   | a
c   | b
c   | d
d   | a
d   | b
d   | c
```

if anyone know plz help me with the code.

Comment: Would a cross join work for you? (See http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-cartesian-joins.htm)

Answer (score 2):

You can use CROSS JOIN with a WHERE clause excluding equal values.

Supposing table name is just table:

```
SELECT a.entry1 as entry3,
       b.entry1 as entry2
  FROM table as a
CROSS JOIN table as b
 WHERE a.entry1<>b.entry1;
```

This provide your desired output, then you will have to work the ALTER TABLE statement.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

to get this use:

```
SELECT t1.entry AS entry2 ,t2.entry AS entry3
FROM mytable t1
LEFT JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.entry <> t2.entry
ORDER BY t1.entry,t2.entry;
```

**Sample**

```
MariaDB []> select entry from mytable;
+-------+
| entry |
+-------+
|     1 |
|     2 |
|     3 |
|     4 |
|     5 |
|     6 |
+-------+
6 rows in set (0.00 sec)

MariaDB []> SELECT t1.entry,t2.entry
    -> FROM mytable t1
    -> LEFT JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.entry <> t2.entry
    -> ORDER BY t1.entry,t2.entry;
+-------+-------+
| entry | entry |
+-------+-------+
|     1 |     2 |
|     1 |     3 |
|     1 |     4 |
|     1 |     5 |
|     1 |     6 |
|     2 |     1 |
|     2 |     3 |
|     2 |     4 |
|     2 |     5 |
|     2 |     6 |
|     3 |     1 |
|     3 |     2 |
|     3 |     4 |
|     3 |     5 |
|     3 |     6 |
|     4 |     1 |
|     4 |     2 |
|     4 |     3 |
|     4 |     5 |
|     4 |     6 |
|     5 |     1 |
|     5 |     2 |
|     5 |     3 |
|     5 |     4 |
|     5 |     6 |
|     6 |     1 |
|     6 |     2 |
|     6 |     3 |
|     6 |     4 |
|     6 |     5 |
+-------+-------+
30 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: @ Bernd Buffen: thanks for the replay.. but i have only one column of data.. see the first table..

Comment: yes - i saw - try it i only use it. i will extend my answer